# UIWebView - scaling multipage PDF ToFit

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a multipage pdf (~14 pages) that I want to load into a UIWebView.

Trouble is that when I activate scalesPageToFit
   - The first page is zoomed to ~50%
   - The page is centered
   - I cannot manually move/scroll the page closer to the page-boundaries

Am using Interface builder.

Any ideas how I can solve this mystery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Apple's QuickLook for better PDF display.
Check out this example code: https://github.com/steipete/PSPDFKit-Demo/blob/master/Examples/PSPDFKitExample/PSPDFQuickLookViewController.m

(It's part of http://PSPDFKit.com)